# Real centroid of a polygon in QGIS 3.2.1? [¿Centroide real de un poligono en QGIS 3.2.1?]

Tags: qgis

alguien sabe como obtener el centroide real de un polígono, en la versión 2.18 había una herramienta con el mismo nombre. ahora en la versión 3.2.1 no esta, quiero obtener el centroide real de polígonos tipo peine que quede el punto dentro del polígono, que no le genere un extend. la herramienta que trae de centroide deja el punto fuera del polígono.

Google Translated

> "someone knows how to get the real centroid of a polygon, in version
>   2.18 there was a tool with the same name. now in version 3.2.1 is not, I want to get the real centroid of comb polygons that is the point
>   inside the polygon, that does not generate an extend. the tool that
>   brings centroid leaves the point outside the polygon."

Comment: QGIS 3.2 Vector -> Geometry tools -> Centroids

Comment: @Mapperz, "point on surface" is the tool. Centroids of some polygons, like banana-shaped ones, can be outside the polygon.

Comment: gracias. ya encontre la solución, por si a alguien le pasa los mismo. sobre la capa del poligono abrir la calculadora y crear dos campos  X y Y de tipo entero real. en la calculadora poner esta consulta: x(point_on_surface($geometry))
y(point_on_surface($geometry)). despues exportar a csv y subirlo con el botón. añadir capa de texto. sube el centroide real dentro del poligono